# invalid operator on multipicklist field

Tags: picklist, multi-select

We have a custom object, Programs that has several multiselect picklists.  One of these is called keywords.  When I look in the field I see that the terms are separated by semicolons.  I do this to execute the query:         keywordsDataList = Database.query(keywordssearchQuery);
The query that I am using is:
keywordssearchQuery is

> SELECT pgm.Id, pgm.Name__c, pgm.Purpose__c, pgm.Type_of_Assistance__c,
> pgm.Categories__c, pgm.Categories_text__c,
> pgm.Program_Eligible_Applicant__c, pgm.Program_Eligible_Projects__c,
> pgm.Application_Process__c, pgm.Available_Funding__c,
> pgm.Contact__r.Name, pgm.Contact__r.Title, pgm.Contact__r.Department,
> pgm.Agency__r.Name, pgm.Contact__r.MailingStreet,
> pgm.Contact__r.MailingCity, pgm.Contact__r.MailingState,
> pgm.Contact__r.Phone, pgm.Contact__r.Fax, pgm.Contact__r.Email,
> pgm.Contact__r.MailingPostalCode, pgm.Keywords__c FROM Program__c pgm
> WHERE (pgm.Keywords__c LIKE '%401K%' ) ORDER BY pgm.Name__c

I get the error message **invalid operator on multipicklist field**.
I am new to salesforce and have no experience in this.  I was very happy that I figured out apex:repeat and all my other fields come out fine for all the records returned.  The only fields that aren’t working are multiselect picklists.  There must be something special I need to do to get those records.  **Any ideas?**

---

As an aside, I was thinking about using String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) instead of just searchKey (which is 401K in this example) but we have a lot of legit terms (like Alzheimer’s) that we need to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use LIKE operator with Multi-select picklist, instead you need to use INCLUDES operator in your case.
Checkout the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm) for details.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!